# mktime shifts a time by one hour

Tags: windows, timezone, mktime

I faced with an interesting problem with mktime function. I use russian time zone (UTC+03:00) Волгоград, Москва, Санкт-Петербург (RTZ 2) / Volgograd, Moscow, Saint Petersburg/ and try to construct time_t for "7.01.2009 00:00:00"

```
tm localTM;

localTM.tm_sec = 0;
localTM.tm_min = 0;
localTM.tm_hour = 0;
localTM.tm_mday = 7;
localTM.tm_mon = 0;
localTM.tm_year = 109;

time_t t = mktime(&localTM);
```

After mktime execution date&time is changed to "6.01.2009 23:00:00".

I have no problems then I construct time for "06.01.2009 00:00:00" or "08.01.2009 00:00:00". 
If I switch time zone to another one, I get no problems with "7.01.2009 00:00:00".

What can be a reason of this oddity, and how can I workaround the issue?

Comment: Too many rule changes in Russia, they just moved from UTC+4 to UTC+3 on October 26th.  How well your operating system can keep track of the rules is unclear when you don't specify what version you use and whether you keep it updated.

Comment: I use Windows 7 Professional, all last updates are installed

Answer (score 1):

When performing conversion to `time_t`, `mktime` needs to guess if the input is DST (Daylight Saving Time) or not. 
For that, `tm.tm_isdst` field is used. See from `man mktime`

> ```
>    tm_isdst  A  flag  that  indicates  whether  daylight saving time is in
>              effect at the time described.  The value is positive if  day-
>              light  saving time is in effect, zero if it is not, and nega-
>              tive if the information is not available.
> ```

Since you do not initialize `tm_isdst` in your code, the default value (`0`) is used, making `mktime` think it's in NO-DST period.
To fix it in your code, simply add

```
 localTM.tm_isdst = -1
```

Note - that logic is necessary as for some moments in time just the "wallclock" information stored in `tm` is not sufficient to determine the exact time.

And yes, the fact that the default behavior is like that is a bit messed up :)